# Laravel 5 wamp redirect to http://www.localhost.com

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, wamp

I use Laravel 5 and wamp. For weeks everything works fine. Today suddenly when calling localhost/myProject in the browser it allways redirects me to http://www.localhost.com/myProject. Other projects work fine. Further I am abble to navigate to http://localhost/phpmyadmin/. Only the url of "myProject" seems not working. Any ideas what can be going wrong? Thank you

My htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
      Options -MultiViews
   </IfModule>

   RewriteEngine On

   # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

   # Handle Front Controller...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you using firefox?

Comment: Yes I'm using firefox

Comment: Did you try in any other browser?

Comment: Let's see the contents of your `.htaccess` file inside `public` folder.

Comment: I tried in IE, but was not working

Comment: I added my htaccess of my public folder

Comment: See if you have other `.htaccess` file in your project's root folder and perhaps look into routes file. You probably changed something somewhere.

Comment: When I use "php artisan serve" I can access the project via http://localhost:8000 . But I get "Invalid request" Unexpected EOF

Comment: Try running `php artisan cache:clear`.